# How to use a struct inside another struct?

Tags: c++, struct

I want to use a nested structure, but I don't know how to enter data in it. For example:

```c
struct A {
    int data;
    struct B;
};

struct B {
    int number;
};
```

So in `main()` when I come to use it:

```c
int main() {
    A stage;
    stage.B.number;
}
```

Is that right? If not how do I use it?

Answer (score 21):

Each member variable of a struct generally has a *name* and a *type*. In your code, the first member of `A` has type `int` and name `data`. The second member only has a type. You need to give it a name. Let's say `b`:

```
struct A {
  int data;
  B b;
};
```

To do that, the compiler needs to already know what `B` is, so declare that struct *before* you declare `A`.

To access a nested member, refer to each member along the path by name, separated by `.`:

```
A stage;
stage.b.number = 5;
```

Comment: ahhh, your the man, so i dont say "struct B" I say "B b" , ok thanks

Comment: Well, you *can* say `struct B`, but again, that's just the *type*. You still need give it a name. (Saying `struct B` instead of just `B` is more of a C style than C++, so if you write code that way, people will think you're weird.)

Comment: The worst thing about it is that his original code is completely legal.  It just doesn't do what he wants it to: his member `struct B;` declares that there is a nested class `A::B`, which will be defined later.  And has nothing to do with the `B` which isn't nested.

Comment: @Shadi if the answer provided helped you solve your problem don't forget to click the check mark next to the question to officially accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 17):

```
struct A {
    struct B {
       int number;
    };
    B b;
    int data;
};
int main() {
    A a;
    a.b.number;
    a.data;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

```
struct B {  // <-- declare before
  int number;
};
struct A {
 int data;
 B b; // <--- declare data member of `B`
 };
```

Now you can use it as,

```
stage.b.number;
```

Answer (score 9):

The `struct B` within `A` must have a name of some sort so you can reference it:

```
struct B {
    int number;
};
struct A {
    int data;
    struct B myB;
};
:
struct A myA;
myA.myB.number = 42;
```

Comment: This is illegal.  The definition of a member type must precede the member.

Answer (score 2):

```
struct A 
{
  int data;
  struct B
  {
    int number;
  }b;
};

int main()
{
  A stage = { 42, {100} };
  assert(stage.data == 42);
  assert(stage.b.number == 100);   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
struct TestStruct {
    short Var1;
    float Var2;
    char Var3;

    struct TestStruct2 {
        char myType;
        CString myTitle;
        TestStruct2(char b1,CString b2):myType(b1), myTitle(b2){}
    };

    std::vector<TestStruct2> testStruct2;

    TestStruct(short a1,float a2,char a3): Var1(a1), Var2(a2), Var3(a3) {
        testStruct2.push_back(TestStruct2(0,"Test Title"));
        testStruct2.push_back(TestStruct2(4,"Test2 Title"));
    }       
};
std::vector<TestStruct> testStruct;

//push smthng to vec later and call 
testStruct.push_back(TestStruct(10,55.5,100));
TRACE("myTest:%s\n",testStruct[0].testStruct2[1].myTitle);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have somewhat like the following code running for a while live now and it works.

```c
// define a timer
struct lightTimer {
  unsigned long time; // time in seconds since midnight so range is 0-86400
  byte percentage; // in percentage so range is 0-100
};
    
// define a list of timers
struct lightTable {
  lightTimer timer[50];
  int otherVar;
};
    
// and make 5 instances
struct lightTable channel[5]; //all channels are now memory allocated
```

@zx485: EDIT: Edited/cleaned the code. Excuse for the raw dump.

Explanation:

Define a lightTimer. Basically a struct that contains 2 vars.

```c
    struct lightTimer {
```

Define a lightTable. First element is a lightTimer.

```
    struct lightTable {
```

Make an actual (named) instance:

```c
    struct lightTable channel[5];
```

We now have 5 channels with 50 timers.

Access like:

```c
    channel[5].timer[10].time = 86400;
    channel[5].timer[10].percentage = 50;
    channel[2].otherVar = 50000;
```

Comment: Surrounding your code sample by some explanation would seriously improve your answer.