# Syntax for declaring an instance of a nested struct

Tags: c++, struct

This is my code:

```
struct mystruct
{  
    int m;
    void setmember(int value);
    int getmember();
    struct mystruct1
    {
        int n;
        void setmember1(int value);
        int getmember1();
    };
};
mystruct A;
```

How do I declare a `mystruct1` variable outside of `mystruct`?

Comment: This question isn't at all clear.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287479/how-to-use-a-struct-inside-another-struct

Comment: First why have you declared mystruct1 inside mystruct ? That is a little weird... Second, why not use a class (you could have a public struct in your class I suppose) ? Third what are you trying to do ?

Comment: @ahesa What would be the difference in using a class with a public structure to a structure with a structure?

Comment: @LincolnTosi That question is not defining the second struct inside the first, it's just using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `mystruct` you can do it as you would expect it to be

```
mystruct1 a;
```

If you are out of scope of `mystruct` you should write

```
mystruct::mystruct1 a;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The second one is what I was looking for.

Comment: @Ella You can thank by accepting the answer and/or upvoting

Comment: @Ella, consider [accepting](http://i.stack.imgur.com/QpogP.png) the answer if it helped.